# How do I set a global variable an alias

Tags: php, variables, foreach

I am sorry. I'm very new in this matter. I've tried to create a global variable to display the content in a different location.

```
$array = array('3 January 2018 - Month - Month of Circumstances',
            '2 February 2018 - Month - A New Advancement', 
            '1 March 2018 - Month - The Threat',
            '31 April 2018 - Month - Month of Prediction',
            '30 May 2018 - Month - Seven Days');

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $item) 
{
  echo preg_replace_callback('/.*-\s*(.*)/', function($match)
  {
    $new_array[] = 'My.Item.' . preg_replace('/\W+/', '.', $match[1]);
  }, $item) . PHP_EOL;
}

print_r($new_array);
```

And the result just:

```
Array
(
)
```

Comment: for what? What is "it"? Please re-read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and update your post to put make all the things you know, but we don't, explicit. You're asking real people for help, they need a good explanation of what you're trying to do, how you've tried doing that, what the result was and how that didn't match what you expected it to be.

Comment: edited. thank you.

Comment: `$new_array` is out of scope for your callback closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @fubar you're `$new_array` is out of scope and you won't be able to access it inside your closure function. You can change your code to something like this.

```
$array = array('3 January 2018 - Month - Month of Circumstances',
            '2 February 2018 - Month - A New Advancement', 
            '1 March 2018 - Month - The Threat',
            '31 April 2018 - Month - Month of Prediction',
            '30 May 2018 - Month - Seven Days');

$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $item) 
{
  $new_array[] = preg_replace_callback('/.*-s*(.*)/', function($match)
  {
     return 'My.Item.' . preg_replace('/W+/', '.', $match[1]);
  }, $item) . PHP_EOL;
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

To access an outside variable inside a function, use the `use()` declaration.

```
foreach($array as $item) 
{
  echo preg_replace_callback('/.*-\s*(.*)/', function($match) use(&$new_array)
  {
    $new_array[] = 'My.Item.' . preg_replace('/\W+/', '.', $match[1]);
  }, $item) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The `&` is necessary to make it a reference to the same variable, rather than a copy, so you can modify it inside the function.